# Printing free state monad as Haskell code

Tags: haskell, free-monad

I've read articles about extending [simple-reflect](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/simple-reflect) [to functions](http://augustss.blogspot.com/2007/10/simpler-easier-in-recent-paper-simply.html) and about representing the State monad as a free monad ([here](https://serokell.io/blog/introduction-to-free-monads)), so now I'd like to try to print some state monads as executable Haskell code, so that for example the monad

```
someComputation :: Num a => State a ()
someComputation = do
  put 42
```

gets printed as `StateT {runStateT = \x0 -> Identity ((),42)}`. For such simple cases, I'm already getting there, but for code involving binds, the output I get is far from my intuition for what should get printed, which is why I'm at a loss for how to edge closer to a solution.

My understanding from the article I linked to above is that `Free` corresponds to `join` and `Pure` to `pure`, so I thought that I could simply map the constructors to `join` and `pure` in the output, insert `fmap` in the right places, and generate unique variable names. Should that work?

For the monad

```
someHarderComputation :: Num a => State a ()
someHarderComputation = do
    i <- get
    put $ i + 1
```

I get the actual output

`StateF {runStateF = \ x1 -> (Free \ x0 -> ("Pure (),x1)",x1 + 1)} $ 1`

though my desired output (for the finished implementation) is

`join ((\x1 -> StateT {runStateT = \x2 -> Identity ((),x1 + 1)}) <$> StateT {runStateT = \x0 -> Identity (x0,x0)})`.

Full code (requires simple-reflect package):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingStrategies #-}
import Control.Arrow
import Control.Monad.Free
import qualified Control.Monad.Trans.State as S
import Data.Functor.Classes
import Data.List
import Debug.SimpleReflect.Expr

newtype StateF s a = StateF { runStateF :: s -> (a, s) }
  deriving stock Functor

deriving instance (ExprArg s, Show s, Show a) => Show (StateF s a)

instance (ExprArg s, Show s) => Show1 (StateF s) where
    liftShowsPrec sp _ d (StateF m) = \str -> show ((first (($ str) . sp 0) . m))

getF :: StateF s s
getF = StateF $ \s -> (s, s)

putF :: s -> StateF s ()
putF s = StateF $ const ((), s)

type State s = Free (StateF s)

get :: State s s
get = liftF getF

put :: s -> State s ()
put = liftF . putF

someComputation :: Num a => State a ()
someComputation = do
  i <- get
  put $ i + 1

instance (Show a, ExprArg a, Show r) => Show (a -> r) where
    show f = "\\ " <> show v <> " -> " <> show (f v)
      where v = S.evalState exprArg vars
            dummy = S.evalState exprArg $ repeat "_"
            vars = supply \\ tokenize (show $ f dummy)
            supply = [ "x" <> show i | i <- [0 :: Int ..]]
            tokenize "" = []
            tokenize s = case lex s of
                (x,s') : _ -> x : tokenize s'
                _ -> error "Assertion error"

class ExprArg a where
    exprArg :: S.State [String] a

instance ExprArg Expr where
    exprArg = do
        vvs <- S.get
        S.put $ tail vvs
        pure (var $ head vvs)

instance ExprArg () where
    exprArg = pure ()

instance (ExprArg a, ExprArg b) => ExprArg (a, b) where
    exprArg = (,) <$> exprArg <*> exprArg

instance (ExprArg a, ExprArg b, ExprArg c) => ExprArg (a, b, c) where
    exprArg = (,,) <$> exprArg <*> exprArg <*> exprArg

printState :: (ExprArg s, Show s, Show a) => State s a -> s -> String
printState (Pure x) s = "pure (" <> show x <> "," <> show s <> ")"
printState (Free m) s =
    show m <> " $ " <> show s

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn $ printState someComputation (1 :: Expr)
```

Comment: There's no `fmap` to insert because they are gone in the free monad.

Comment: Your expected output contains the string "<$>". Why did you expect that? Can you point to the part of the code that you expected to produce that string?

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks for pointing that out. I've rephrased it to make clear that that's the desired output, where I didn't write the code to produce the string "<$>" yet as I want to first figure out why the order of expressions is so different from my expectations.

Comment: I don't strictly see what you are looking for. Would you be fine with `foldFree Identity $ StateF {runStateF = \ x1 -> (Free \ x0 -> ("Pure (),x1)",x1 + 1)} $ 1`? If not, how is it worse than the desired outcome, is that only a matter of being sufficiently reduced?